# C++ QT Add a widget to scroll area without layout

Tags: c++, qt

so I an new to C++ and QT and I am trying to add a widget to a scroll area but without a layout as I want the widgets to be click and dragged.

Here's my code (main window.cpp):

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include "player_window.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}
void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    player_window *player = new player_window(ui->scrollArea_WidgetContents);
    player->setGeometry(50,50,450,130);
    ui->scrollArea_WidgetContents->layout()->addWidget(player);

}
```

Thanks!

Comment: remove `ui->scrollArea_WidgetContents->layout()->addWidget(player)` and add `player->show();`

Comment: @eyllanesc Thanks! It Works!